# How to collect all the values for a SettingKey across all projects for use in an sbt plugin?

Tags: sbt-plugin, sbt1.0

I am trying to collect the set of values for `libraryDependencies` across all projects/scopes/etc in an sbt 1.x build.

What is the right way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

I came to the answer courtesy of `@gpoirier` in the [Gitter sbt/sbt](https://gitter.im/sbt/sbt) room:

```
val extracted = Project.extract(state.value)
import extracted._

val allLibraryDependencies = structure.allProjectRefs.flatMap({ p =>
  get(libraryDependencies in p)
}).distinct
```